# managing file names with AngularJS-Route

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I am new to AngularJS and need your help to solve an issue.
I am using angular-route.js to navigate through different templates. Since every template has its own set of JS files i was thinking about making a variable to call them dynamicly such as:

```
<script src="assets/{{ FolderName }}/controller.js"></script>
<script src="assets/{{ FolderName }}/service.js"></script>
```

I was hoping to use the **"resolve"** feature of AngularRoute but i have no idea how to do so.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute','ui.bootstrap'])

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider, $scope) {
$routeProvider.when('/home', {templateUrl: 'templates/home.php', controller: 'homeCtrl'});
$routeProvider.when('/register', {templateUrl: 'templates/register.php',resolve: { FolderName: 'Register', fileLoader: function(FolderName){ return FolderName.query(); } },  controller: 'registerCtrl'});
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
}]);
```

Is it possible that i can have a variable/Scope "FolderName" to be dynamic which i can use as folder name to call dynamic JS files with reference to the pages

Comment: can you explain better how you are including your templates, but also, what kind of files are you using inside your templates?

Comment: I have different folders for Login, Register etc. and each folder has its own set of controller.js and service.js .... if i can only make the folder name dynamic i can call the relevant JS files when viewer is on Login page or home page etc.

Comment: import that files in the index, not in the html of the view, then you should use grunt or similar to minify and uglify your js code